# Update content of user defined UIView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` with cells, that contains `UIScrollView` and inside it, there is a user defined `UIView` (via XIB)

I am using this code to init cell with data:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        for v in cell.contentView.subviews {

            if let scroll: UIScrollView = v as? UIScrollView {
                scroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

                for s in scroll.subviews {
                    if let content: DetailedView = s as? DetailedView {
                        content.fillData()
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

In my DetailedView, I have:

```
@IBDesignable
class DetailedView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnTemp: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    // Performs the initial setup.
    private func setupView() {
        let view = viewFromNibForClass()
        view.frame = bounds

        // Auto-layout stuff.
        view.autoresizingMask = [
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        ]

        addSubview(view)
    }

    // Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.
    private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return view
    }

    func fillData(){
        self.btnTemp.titleLabel?.text = "btn temp"

        print("fill data")

    }


    @IBAction func btnTempClick(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Click")
    }
}
```

All is working - view is visible, `btnTempClick` is called, but `fillData` is not working. It does not change content of button, there is still default text "Button". How to fix this?

Comment: shouldn't it be self.btnTemp.setTitle("btn temp", for:.normal)

Comment: @Joshua You are right, I am an idiot :-) ... post it as asnwer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it official removing it from comment and putting it as an answer.

have you tried using `self.btnTemp.setTitle("btn temp", for:.normal)`?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try with setTitle forControlState